# Throwing an exception of the proper type

Tags: c#, .net, exception

In my code I have often situations like this:

```
public void MyMethod(string data)
{
    AnotherClass objectOfAnotherClass = GetObject(data);
    if (objectOfAnotherClass == null)
        throw new WhatExceptionType1("objectOfAnotherClass is null.");

    if (objectOfAnotherClass.SomeProperty < 0)
        throw new WhatExceptionType2("SomeProperty must not be negative.");
}
```

Imagine that `GetObject` makes use of some external libraries which are not under my control and that this library returns `null` if no object for `data` exists and considers a negative `SomeProperty` as a valid state and therefore doesn't throw an exception. Further imagine that `MyMethod` cannot work without `objectOfAnotherClass` and does not make sense with a negative `SomeProperty`.

What are the proper exceptions for `WhatExceptionType1/2` to throw in this situation?

Basically I had four options in mind:

- 1) `InvalidOperationException`, because `MyMethod` doesn't make sense under the conditions described above. On the other hand the guidelines (and Intellisense in VS too) say that an InvalidOperationException should be thrown if the object the method belongs to is in an invalid state. Now the object itself isn't in an invalid state. Instead the input parameter `data` and some other operations based on this parameter lead to a situation where `MyMethod` cannot operate anymore.
- 2) `ArgumentException`, because there are values for `data` the method can work with and other values the method can't. But I cannot check this by inspecting `data` alone, I have to call other operations before I decide.
- 3) `Exception`, because I don't know which other exception type to use and because all other predefined exceptions feel too specialized and not fitting to my situation.
- 4) `MyCustomException` (my own exception type derived from `Exception`). This seems always an option but I am worried that I have to define lots of special exception classes for many different error conditions when I start to follow this pattern.

Are there other and better options? What are the arguments in favor or against those options?

Thank you for feedback in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful when using built-in exception types... they have very specific meanings to the .NET framework, and unless you are using it for *exactly* the same meaning, it's better to roll your own (+1 to John Saunders for `Serializeable`).

`InvalidOperationException` has the meaning:

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state.

For example, if you call `SqlConnection.Open()`, you get an `InvalidOperationException` if you haven't specified a data source.  `InvalidOperationException`isn't appropriate for your scenario.

`ArgumentException` isn't appropriate, either.  The failure to create `objectOfAnotherClass` may have nothing to do with bad data being passed in. Suppose it's a filename, but `GetObject()` doesn't have permissions to read the file.  As the method is written, there's no way to know why the call to `GetObject()` failed, and the best you can say is the object returned was null or invalid.

`Exception` is just a bad idea, in general... it gives the caller absolutely no idea why the method failed to create the object.  (For that matter, having only a `catch (Exception ex) {..}` is a bad idea, too)

You want exceptions that clearly identify what went wrong, and that means creating your own.  Try to keep them generic to avoid 1,000 custom exceptions.  I suggest:

```
ObjectCreateException:   // The call to GetObject() returned null<br />
InvalidObjectException:  // The object returned by GetObject() is invalid 
                         // (because the property < 0)
```

Thanks for the vote ~ thought I would add an example of some custom exceptions we've written.

Note that you don't really need to add any code to the methods, because the custom exceptions don't really do anything differently than their base classes; they just represent something different.  The second example does add a property to the exception, so there's code to support it (including constructors).

The first is a generic base for all of our exceptions; the rule "Don't catch general Exceptions" applies (though we do it anyway... it allows us to differentiate between exceptions we generated and exceptions thrown by the framework).  The second is a more specific exception that derives from `Gs3Exception` and serializes a custom property.

The .NET development team decided `ApplicationException` had no real-world value and deprecated it, but the purist in me always liked it, so it persists in my code.  Here, though, it really does add no value and only increases the depth of the inheritance heirarchy.  So feel free to inherit directly from `Exception` instead.

```
/// <summary>
/// A general, base error for GS3 applications </summary>
[Serializable]
public class Gs3Exception : ApplicationException {


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Gs3Exception"/> class </summary>
    public Gs3Exception() {}


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Gs3Exception"/> class </summary>
    /// <param name="message">A brief, descriptive message about the error </param>
    public Gs3Exception(string message) : base(message) {}


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Gs3Exception"/> class 
    /// when deserializing </summary>
    /// <param name="info">The object that holds the serialized object data </param>
    /// <param name="context">The contextual information about the source or
    ///  destination.</param>
    public Gs3Exception(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Gs3Exception"/> class
    /// with a message and inner exception </summary>
    /// <param name="Message">A brief, descriptive message about the error </param>
    /// <param name="exc">The exception that triggered the failure </param>
    public Gs3Exception(string Message, Exception exc) : base(Message, exc) { }


}


/// <summary>
/// An object queried in an request was not found </summary>
[Serializable]
public class ObjectNotFoundException : Gs3Application {

    private string objectName = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ObjectNotFoundException"/> class </summary>
    public ObjectNotFoundException() {}


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ObjectNotFoundException"/> class </summary>
    /// <param name="message">A brief, descriptive message about the error</param>
    public ObjectNotFoundException(string message) : base(message) {}


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ObjectNotFoundException"/> class </summary>
    /// <param name="ObjectName">Name of the object not found </param>
    /// <param name="message">A brief, descriptive message about the error </param>
    public ObjectNotFoundException(string ObjectName, string message) : this(message) {
        this.ObjectName = ObjectName;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ObjectNotFoundException"/> class.
    /// This method is used during deserialization to retrieve properties from 
    /// the serialized data. </summary>
    /// <param name="info">The object that holds the serialized object data.</param>
    /// <param name="context">The contextual information about the source or
    /// destination.</param>
    public ObjectNotFoundException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) {
        if (null != info) {
            this.objectName = info.GetString("objectName");
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// When serializing, sets the <see cref="T:System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo"/> 
    /// with information about the exception. </summary>
    /// <param name="info">The <see cref="T:System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo"/> that holds 
    /// the serialized object data about the exception being thrown.</param>
    /// <param name="context">The <see cref="T:System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext"/> that contains contextual information about the source or destination.</param>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">
    /// The <paramref name="info"/> parameter is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) </exception>
    /// <PermissionSet>
    ///     <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Read="*AllFiles*" PathDiscovery="*AllFiles*"/>
    ///     <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Flags="SerializationFormatter"/>
    /// </PermissionSet>
    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {

        base.GetObjectData(info, context);

        //  'info' guaranteed to be non-null (base.GetObjectData() will throw an ArugmentNullException if it is)
        info.AddValue("objectName", this.objectName);

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the object not found </summary>
    /// <value>The name of the object </value>
    public string ObjectName {
        get { return objectName; }
        set { objectName = value; }
    }

}
```

PS:  Before anyone calls me on it, the reason for a base `Gs3Exception` that adds no more value than the `ApplicationException` is the Enterprise Library Exception Handling Application Block... by having an application-level base exception, we can create general logging policies for exceptions thrown directly by our code.

Comment: Added some examples of our custom exceptions; feel free to use them as a template.  Thanks for the vote!

Comment: Great, thanks for your effort! I especially like the idea to have a base class for all custom exceptions in the library to distinguish them easily from the built-in .NET exceptions and also to create only a few exceptions which are general enough to cover more than one exceptional case in the code.

Answer (score 8):

If built-in exceptions exist that make sense, I would use those. If not, it makes sense to roll your own exception -- even if it's an empty class that extends Exception -- because this allows you to detect specific exception types. If you just threw Exception, for example, how do you know the exception was because `objectOfAnotherClass` was null, and that it wasn't some exception raised in `GetObject`?

So to summarize: **specific exceptions are better, because you can (potentially) diagnose and recover from specific cases.** Hence, use the built-in .NET exceptions (if they're sufficient), or else roll your own exceptions.

**Edit:** I should clarify that I rarely use existing exceptions and put a message in them. It makes your code more readable if the exception type tells you the error, rather than having to debug, generate the exception, and then inspect the message to see what the problem is.

Comment: But specific exceptions need to be created (properly: are yours Serializable?), and maintained, and if all they do is "make your code more readable", then you should do without.

Comment: To your Edit: I am really afraid that I end up with too many custom exception types if I follow this pattern. It might be helpful for debugging purposes but if you think from the viewpoint of a user who has to be notified what went wrong or of a logging system where errors have to be reported a clear message is much more important than the type of the exception, in my opinion. But if I understand you correctly in the special case described in my question you would prefer option (4), right?

Comment: @John Saunders: I concur. You throw a new NullPointerException() and not a new Exception("Null pointer") because reading catch (NullPointerException) is more specific. Catching specific exceptions is the first benefit; readability is a great side-effect.

Comment: @Slauma: See my comment to John. I prefer to catch a specific exception type, rather than to catch a generic exception and dig into the message to see if it's what I expect. If it makes sense, sure, reuse all the .NET built-in exceptions and stuff a message into them if it helps. Yes, I would choose #4, but only because #1 and #2 don't seem to fit exactly for you. (If you decide that they're "good enough", then do that instead of #4.)

Comment: @ashes: the reason to catch a specific type is because your code will do something different when that type is caught. If your code behaves the same for `Exception` as it does for `SpecificException`, then use `Exception` instead.

Comment: Slauma>  Make your custom exceptions as general as possible, so that they can be reused for other scenarios.  E.G. `InvalidObjectException`

Comment: @James B: Yes, that's actually the way I am now mainly thinking about. I believe that would best fit to my needs.

Comment: @JohnSaunders If someone can't easily figure out what your code is doing 6 months from now, then your attempts at good design weren't very successful. Readability, in my opinion, has more impact on maintainability than any other factor. If that means I need *more* pieces that have to be maintained, that's okay; at least I *can* maintain them. "Makes your code more readable" is one of the the best reasons to do *anything* in programming; I would say it's second only to making your code behave correctly. I don't have much opinion on this question, but I totally disagree with your reasoning.

Comment: @jpmc26: how do custom exceptions make your code more readable? How is `throw new CustomException("Message");` more readable than `throw new Exception("Message");`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders That's why I said, "I don't have much opinion on this question, but I totally disagree with your reasoning." Your initial comment suggests that improved readability is not a valid reason for a particular coding choice. If you meant that custom exceptions don't make your code more readable, that's a different issue that I don't have a strong opinion on.

Answer (score 4):

My vote would be `ArgumentException` in at least the first case if not both; ArgumentExceptions should be thrown, quote, "when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid". If MyMethod cannot use the argument `data` to create a valid instance of `AnotherClass`, as expected by MyMethod, the argument is invalid for use in MyMethod.

Understand that unless you plan on catching exceptions of different types and handling them differently, exactly which exception is thrown really doesn't matter. Some exceptions (like ArgumentNullException) create a custom message based on very little information and so are easy to set up and localize, others (like SqlExceptions) have more specific data about what went wrong, but all of that is superfluous if all you want is to throw out an exception saying "Oops!".

Comment: Disagree... the failure to create `objectOfAnotherClass` may have nothing to do with bad data being passed in.  Suppose it's a filename, but `GetObject()` doesn't have permissions to read the file.  As written, there's no way to know why the call to `GetObject()` failed, and the best you can say is `ObjectCreateException` (returned null) or `InvalidObjectException` (property is negative).

Comment: If GetObject is performing some file operation, it SHOULD let various exceptions relating to the file operation be thrown out, instead of trapping and returning null. Given that, if GetObject returns null, it must think that's appropriate for the data being passed, which may be valid elsewhere but not here. Instead of requiring GetObject to know the context, MyMethod interrogates the result and throws an exception if the result cannot be used, the logical inference being GIGO.

Answer (score 4):

The appropriate thing to do here is to *not* throw an exception if you can help it.  There are two basic pieces of information that are missing to do the Right Thing.  First there's the string argument, apparently the caller of this method has some secret knowledge of how GetObject() works to know what the appropriate string should be.  You thus need to treat the caller as an authority, he knows a lot more about GetObject() than you do.

Second is the GetObject() behavior.  Apparently the author designed it so that it is *non-exceptional* and expected for it to return a null.  A much stronger contract would be two methods, TryGetObject() and GetObject(), the latter one throwing.  Or more commonly an extra argument for GetObject() named *throwOnFailure*.  But that didn't happen, null is returned and normal.

You are breaking that contract here.  You are trying to turn it from non-exceptional to exceptional, but without having any clue what is wrong.  The very best thing to do is to not change that contract and leave it up to the caller of your method deal with this.  After all, that's the one that knows what GetObject() does.  Change the name of the method, use the word "Try", and return a bool.

This is all assuming that the author of GetObject() knew what he was doing.  If he didn't, there's little you can do to improve the situation.  Throw ArgumentException if you have reason to think that the caller might have screwed up, NullReferenceException if you think that the GetObject() author might have a bug in his code.

Comment: +1 for stating that the caller is the authority... as written, this is just a helper class.  The piece that is missing is:  what are you doing with `objectOfAnotherClass`... are you returning that to the caller?  Or is your method encapsulating actions that you want to perform on `objectOfAnotherClass`?  If you're returning the object to the caller, Hans is still correct... `bool TryGetObject(ref AnotherClass objectOfAnotherClass) {..}` is the way to go.  If you're encapsulating, the caller knows details about the inner workings of `AnotherClass` that it shouldn't know.

Comment: @James B: Your second guess is true: I don't return the object to the caller, I only use `objectOfAnotherClass` temporarily to produce some results the caller wants to have. And no, the caller doesn't know how `AnotherClass` internally works, but he knows for which `data` he gives to my method `GetObject` will succeed IF there aren't very unexpected external influences causing it to fail (see also my comment to Stephen Cleary's answer).

Comment: In my opinion I don't break a contract, I am actually defining my own contract and tell the caller: "Give me correct valid data or I will throw an exception. Don't use my method to test if there is an object belonging to `data`." In the context of the project this makes sense, because the caller knows the valid data in advance and is only interested to call the method with those valid data. It is very unexpected for the caller that the method fails.

Comment: The caller doesn't know what AnotherClass does internally, but he does know what AnotherClass needs to be created... which makes the caller the authority.  If MyMethod() were encapsulating the functionality of AnotherClass, the caller would not know anything about creating AnotherClass.  The caller might do something like Customer.GetAddress(), where the call to GetAddress() needs AnotherClass to look up the address... but only Customer or the GetAddress() call itself know what AnotherClass needs to be created.  It's a bit purist here; helper classes tend to violate encapsulation, anyway.

Comment: @Slauma - then make it unexpected and make sure it isn't any catchable since the caller doesn't expect failure by your words.    You're trying to solve a problem that shouldn't be solved.  Don't throw an exception at all.  Use the object as-is.  It's going to bomb appropriately.  NullReferenceException, should never be caught.

Answer (score 3):

How about using the ObjectNotFoundException.  That would describe the situation correctly.

Comment: Isn't `ObjectNotFoundException` a very ADO.NET/Entity Framework specific exception type? In my situation `GetObject` does not necessarily call a database and I also wouldn't like to reference the `System.Data.Entity` assembly only for this exception type.

Comment: That is true, however if you feel that you want one exception to cover all of the above exceptions, then I would create a custom exception like AssertionException.  This should help you track what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

First, categorize the error. Eric Lippert [on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) has the best categorization I've seen: fatal, boneheaded, vexing, and exogenous. Your exception would not be fatal; it would be one of: boneheaded, vexing, or exogenous.

The error is *boneheaded* if you can say that for a correct input `name`, you know that `GetObject` will return an object that makes sense for your method. In other words, the only cause for those exceptions is bugs in the code calling `MyMethod`. In this case, it doesn't really matter what exception type you use because you should never see it in production anyway - `ArgumentException` (if the problem was with `name`) or `InvalidOperationException` (if the problem was with the state of the object defining `MyMethod`) would be fine choices in that situation, but the specific exception type shouldn't be documented (or else it becomes part of the API).

The error is *vexing* if `GetObject` is predictable with respect to `name` (i.e., for a given `name` you will either always get a valid object or never get a valid object), but `name` is based on user input (or configuration). In this case, you don't want to throw an exception at all; you want to write a `TryMyMethod` method so that the calling code doesn't have to catch an exception to deal with a non-exceptional situation.

The error is *exogenous* if `GetObject`'s behavior is unpredictable with respect to `name`: some external influence may cause `name` to become valid or invalid. In this case, you do have to choose a specific exception type *and document it* as part of the API. `ArgumentException` would not be a good choice for an exogenous exception; neither would `InvalidOperationException`. You should choose something more like `FileNotFoundException`, more descriptive of the underlying problem (whatever `GetObject` does).

Comment: Reading this categorization and the linked blog post in more detail I believe the error type which could cause the first problem in my code is `exogenous` because the only reason why the caller and also my code could expect `GetObject` to fail is an external influence (file system error, database error, webservice down, someone deleted the object, etc.). I can expect that the caller only gives me `data` which will `GetObject` make succeed EXCEPT external sources not under control of the caller's and my code will cause an unexpected failure. (continued...)

Comment: (...continued) The problem is only, I don't know what `GetObject` exactly does internally, so I cannot throw a specific error. The only specific exception I could throw is a `GetObjectReturnedUnexpectedNullException`.

Comment: @Slauma: in that case, I suggest you define your own exception class as you stated, and note it in the API docs.

Comment: @Slauma - what kind of exception is the second error condition?

Comment: @Jeff Sternal: It's a quite hypothetical exception. The object returned by `GetObject` is very large and complex. `MyMethod` only extracts a few fields from it and can only do its work if various properties and enumerations have specific values or are in a specific range. The caller of `MyMethod` knows this but I am not sure if he will (`boneheaded` exception?) and if he can (`exogenous` exception?) check all conditions in advance. I'm inclined to treat it like the "GetObject returns null" case as exogenous and throw a suitable custom exception - `InvalidObjectStateException` or so.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is far, far too late to be of use to the OP, but I'm inclined to think the difficulty here is more of a code smell. If we consider the Single Responsibility Principle at the level of a method instead of just a class, then it appears this method violates it. It does 2 things: it parses `data` and then does further processing. So the right thing to do is eliminate one responsibility, namely the parsing. You can do this by changing your argument to an instance of `AnotherClass`. Then it becomes clear what you should do:

```
public void MyMethod(AnotherClass data)
{
    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("data is null.");

    if (data.SomeProperty < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("data.SomeProperty must not be negative.");

    ...
}
```

It then becomes the caller's responsibility to call the parsing method and deal with this situation. They may choose to catch the exception or pre-check it before calling the method. The caller has to do a little more work, but with the benefit of increased flexibility. For example, this also gives the benefit of allowing alternate constructions of `AnotherClass`; callers may build it up in code instead of parsing it or call some alternate parsing method.

Comment: Late answer, but nonetheless useful :) I think it goes into the same direction as my own comment under Wim.van.Gool's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you plan to handle exceptions in your appliation.  Custom exceptions are nice in a try/catch situations but try/catches are also expensive.  If you don't plan on catching and handling your custom exception, then: throw new Exception("Index out of range: SomeProperty must not be negative."); is just as useful as a custom exception.

```
public class InvalidStateException : ApplicationException
{
   ...
}
```

In your code:

```
// test for null
if(objectOfAnotherClass == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Object cannot be null");

// test for valid state
if(objectOfAnotherClass.SomeProperty < 0) throw new InvalidStateException("Object is in an invalid state");
```

Comment: Good point that the way of throwing exceptions can depend on the way of handling exceptions in my application! But my question is more from the viewpoint of a library developer who doesn't know who and which applications will use the library and has to follow some standard rules which application developers will expect from a library.

Comment: I see.  Then derive a new exception from ApplicationException and name it based on something useful like the caller's current action, in other words group them logically.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the post of Stephen Cleary that you should try to categorize your exception and then find the Exception-type to throw accordingly. I find the categorization of Eric Lippert quite interesting and in many ways he is right, *but*, I've been thinking about another type of categorization that looks somewhat like the categorization of Lippert except that I focus more on *code contracts*. What I propose to do is to categorize `Exceptions` in failed **preconditions**, **postconditions** and plain **errors**.

The thing is: every method has a formal contract in the sense that if you satisfy all preconditions, it promises to satisfy some postconditions for you. Generally, all preconditions can be subdivided into three types:

- Security-related (is the caller authorized to make the call?)
- Context-related (is the object in the right state to make the call?)
- Input-related (has the caller specified valid arguments?)

In principle, every method should check these conditions in order and throw one of the following exception types (the exact type or derivative):

- `SecurityException`
- `InvalidOperationException`
- `ArgumentException`

These exceptions communicate to the caller that it was 'their fault' something went wrong and the call could not complete correctly. However, if all preconditions are satisfied according to the formal specification of the method, and the method detects it cannot meet the specified postconditions, it should throw an `Exception` of a type that clearly communicates *what* went wrong. You would typically want to define your own Exception type for these situations or re-use an existing Exception type, as long as it's not one of the types that are reserved for precondition-failures.

And finally, errors are `Exceptions` that are thrown by the CLR that can occur virtually anyplace, anytime, and are virtually impossible to predict. They will never be explicitly part of your methods and as such should never be thrown (neither specifically handled) by user code. In this sense, they map almost one-to-one to the fatal exceptions of Lippert.

So what should you do in my view in the case presented by Slauma?

Well, as you can imagine, it entirely depends on the contracts of `MyMethod(data)`, `GetObject(data)` and `objectOfAnotherClass.SomeProperty`. What does the API of `GetObject(data)` say about in which situations it will return `null` (or throw it's own exceptions)? What is the exact meaning and specification of `SomeProperty`?

Suppose that `GetObject(data)` is a method that returns an object retrieved from a database and that `data` is the object's identifier. If the contract of `GetObject(data)` specifies that it will return `null` if no object with identifier `data` exists, then your design should take that into account in it's own contract. You might want to force the caller, if that's reasonable, to always specify a value for `data` such that `GetObject(data)` does not return `null` and if it does, you may throw an `ArgumentException` (or derivative) to indicate the fault on caller's side.

On the other hand, if `GetObject(data)` specified that it only returns null when the caller has insufficient rights to retrieve the object, you may throw a `SecurityException` (or derivative) to indicate the problem to the caller of `MyMethod(data)`.

Finally, if `GetObject(data)` promises it will 'never' return `null`, and it still does, you may allow your code to crash with a `NullReferenceException` (because righteously assuming it will never be `null`) or handle the situation specifically when you are dealing with sensitive code, throwing your own Exception-type (since a postcondition, from the caller of MyMethod's perspective, has failed).

The second case is slightly more complex but can be approached much the same way. Suppose that `objectOfAnotherClass` presented a row or entity that was fetched from a database by identifier `data`, and `MyMethod(data)` clearly specified that `data` should specify an identifier of an object where `objectOfAnotherClass.SomeProperty >= 0`, then in this case throwing an ArgumentException (or derivative) would be part of your design.

Then again, when `MyMethod(data)` operates in a context where the caller may assume that a valid identifier will never return an object such that `objectOfAnotherClass.SomeProperty < 0`, (or better: is not even aware that such object exists) then such occurrence is truly unexpected on the caller's site and `MyMethod(data)` should either not even check the case explicitly (again, because assuming it will not occur) or, if going for more robust code, throw a specific, custom Exception indicating the problem.

To conclude: I think determining the type of `Exception` to throw solely depends on the formal contracts every method has with it's callers and callees. If the caller fails to satisfy a precondition, a method should always respond to the caller by throwing a `SecurityException`, `InvalidOperationException` or `ArgumentException`. If the method itself fails to meet it's own postconditions, or may either crash on exceptions thrown by the CLR or other components, or throw it's own more specific Exception indicating the problem.

Comment: +1: Thanks for this comprehensive and very well thought answer! And that after more than a year after I almost can't remember to ever have asked this question.

Comment: BTW: Today I'd say that my method `MyMethod(string data)` has a bad design and shouldn't exist. If the method really cannot work with `objectOfAnotherClass==null` and `objectOfAnotherClass.SomeProperty<0` then the signature should be: `MyMethod(AnotherClass objectOfAnotherClass)`. The caller is responsible to load the object via another method, check the preconditions and, if OK, pass the object into the method. If the preconditions aren't met the method throws `ArgumentNullException` or `ArgumentException`. Or: The method violates SRP: Loading data and processing the data should be separated.